# How can I change the data type of `puVar1` in this C++ function?

Tags: disassembly, c++, ghidra, android, api-reversing

I was `reversing` ( *new to the reversing world of course*) being using `Ghidra` for this. I get a C++ function `AppChat::__Status::setDescription(ErrorCode param_1)`. Within this function, there's a variable `puVar1` declared as `undefined8 *`. However, I need to change the data type of `puVar1` to a different type like `char` to better format its usage in the code. I mean for example, the variable `*pcVar3;` which the `decompiler` defines as `char` is presenting the string as expected in the code. but the variable `puVar` is not.

Here is the relevant code:

```
void AppChat::__Status::setDescription(ErrorCode param_1)

{
  undefined8 *puVar1;
  undefined8 *in_x8;
  undefined8 uVar2;
  char *pcVar3;
  undefined8 uVar4;
  undefined8 uVar5;
  
  switch(param_1) {
  case 0x26ac:
    *(undefined *)in_x8 = 0x1a;
    *(undefined8 *)((long)in_x8 + 6) = 0x726f727265206e77;
    *(undefined8 *)((long)in_x8 + 1) = 0x206e776f6e6b6e55;
    *(undefined *)((long)in_x8 + 0xe) = 0;
    break;
  case 0x26ad:
    puVar1 = (undefined8 *)operator.new(0x40);
    in_x8[1] = 0x36;
    *in_x8 = 0x41;
    in_x8[2] = puVar1;
    *(undefined8 *)((long)puVar1 + 0x2e) = 0x746e65696c437461;
    puVar1[3] = 0x54202e6465727567;
    puVar1[2] = 0x69666e6f6320746f;
    puVar1[5] = 0x7461684320707574;
    puVar1[4] = 0x6573206f74207972;
    puVar1[1] = 0x6e207369206e6f69;
    *puVar1 = 0x746163696c707041;
    *(undefined *)((long)puVar1 + 0x36) = 0;
    break;
  case 0x26ae:
    *(undefined *)in_x8 = 0x1e;
    in_x8[1] = 0x74756f656d697420;
    *(undefined8 *)((long)in_x8 + 1) = 0x2074736575716552;
    *(undefined *)(in_x8 + 2) = 0;
    break;
  case 0x26af:
    puVar1 = (undefined8 *)operator.new(0x30);
    in_x8[2] = puVar1;
    *(undefined4 *)((long)puVar1 + 0x1f) = 0x74737269;
    in_x8[1] = 0x23;
    *in_x8 = 0x31;
    puVar1[1] = 0x70202c6465746365;
    *puVar1 = 0x6e6e6f6320746f4e;
    puVar1[3] = 0x6966207463656e6e;
    puVar1[2] = 0x6f6320657361656c;
    *(undefined *)((long)puVar1 + 0x23) = 0;
    break;
  case 0x26b0:
    puVar1 = (undefined8 *)operator.new(0x20);
    pcVar3 = "Network connection error";
    goto LAB_003191e8;
  case 0x26b1:
    puVar1 = (undefined8 *)operator.new(0x20);
    in_x8[2] = puVar1;
    in_x8[1] = 0x17;
    *in_x8 = 0x21;
    *(undefined8 *)((long)puVar1 + 0xf) = 0x656c696620656874;
    puVar1[1] = 0x74206e65706f2074;
    *puVar1 = 0x6f6e20646c756f43;
    *(undefined *)((long)puVar1 + 0x17) = 0;
    break;
  default:
    if (param_1 == 0x1f7) {
      *(undefined *)in_x8 = 0x26;
      *(undefined4 *)(in_x8 + 2) = 0x454c4241;
      *(undefined8 *)((long)in_x8 + 9) = 0x414c494156414e55;
      *(undefined8 *)((long)in_x8 + 1) = 0x2045434956524553;
      *(undefined *)((long)in_x8 + 0x14) = 0;
      return;
    }
    if (param_1 != 0x4b3) {
      *(undefined2 *)in_x8 = 0;
      return;
    }
    puVar1 = (undefined8 *)operator.new(0x20);
    pcVar3 = "The file size is too big";
LAB_003191e8:
    uVar2 = *(undefined8 *)((long)pcVar3 + 0x10);
    uVar5 = *(undefined8 *)((long)pcVar3 + 8);
    uVar4 = *(undefined8 *)pcVar3;
    in_x8[2] = puVar1;
    in_x8[1] = 0x18;
    *in_x8 = 0x21;
    puVar1[2] = uVar2;
    puVar1[1] = uVar5;
    *puVar1 = uVar4;
    *(undefined *)(puVar1 + 3) = 0;
  }
  return;
}
```

**so far** I tried to select the variable `puVar1` in the `ghidra` decompiler then right clicked I choose `retype variable` and set `data type` as  `char *` but it creates as new variable and changes the `data` held in `pVar1` to `pVar2` with `undefined8`

[image: choosing retype variable option]

[image]

so I am doing slightly something wrong as I believe. the variable `pcVar3` holds the string data as readable like for example `Network connection error`. but the variable `puVar1` is not held in a format such that the data can be read. like for example it holds `0x746163696c707041` and if changed to `character` it reads as `tacilppA` which is reverse order of the string as expected. this has to do with `little endianness` I am new to this reversing on the platform. so my question is how can I re adjust the variable as it seem in the code as `char array`? is data type change needed?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, you cannot change the data type for some underlying reasons. There is a good explanation [here](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/discussions/2564) from one of the developper (`emteere`):

> The `undefined` datatypes are used to note an access of a size without knowing the real type, or the existence of a parameter without locking in the type. They are really placeholder types. The decompiler is free to propagate a type and replace the undefined with a good type for all undefined types. In addition, undefined types defined in memory can be replaced with a more specific type by algorithms.
>
> If the decompiler were to use `uint8_t`, that could be incorrect as the type might be signed. It all depends on the access. The decompiler will try to replace the type with a correct type based on the access or use. Absent any other type information than a size, especially when accessing through an unknown pointer type, the decompiler will display undefined. If the pointer points to a structure or class, the decompiler is more likely to use `uint`, `char`, `byte`, etc... as the type for local variables and parameters.
>
> There is a setting to disable type casts, which could help improve default display if you don't specify types for parameters which you could try as well.